# DWM Screen Capturing with DirectX IDXGIOutput::GetDisplaySurfaceData

Tags: directx, dwm, dxgi

I am trying to capture DWM's DirectX surface by using DXGI and `GetDisplaySurfaceData()` using Direct3D 10/11.

However, when I am taking ownership of the adapter's output with `IDXGIOutput::TakeOwnership()` before calling to `GetDisplaySurfaceData()`, the whole screen blacks out for a moment and then restores back (just as during display mode switching).

Why does this happen, and how can I prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is extremely late. But for what it's worth, the documentation explicitly says that you are not supposed to call TakeOwnership() directly as the results will be unpredictable.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174558(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: But this doesn't really answer how to avoid calling `TakeOwnership`, as it seems to be an requirement according to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/29698887/1175813